# Schema:update for test environnement

Tags: symfony, doctrine

With Symfony 4.2 and Doctrine, I have two `.env` files :

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://me:password@127.0.0.1:3306/base
```

**.env.test**

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://me:password@127.0.0.1:3306/base_test
```

If I do the `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` command : **base** is updated. **✓**

If I do the `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test` command : **base_test** is *not* updated. **✘** I have this message in my console :

> [OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Comment: Did you tried to rename your env file to `.env.dev`? I'm not sure, but i think the file name and the `--env` parameter have to be the same.

Comment: Sorry, it's error. I have --env=test parameter and same result

Comment: Have you tried using `APP_ENV=test php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` instead? The env-option is deprecated. I don't think that's the cause, but maybe it helps. Please also try running the command using `-vvv` to get more verbose output.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As from the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html) you should place `APP_ENV=test` in the `.env.test` file and run command like so

```
APP_ENV=test php bin/console command_name
```

Comment: This did not run the command on test environment on Symfony 4. In the logs you can see it was executed on prod environment with the message: `! [CAUTION] This operation should not be executed in a production environment!`